# class type redefinition in cpp file

Tags: c++, file, header

I made a cpp and h file and created classes in them but i got a error with redefinition such as

> Error 2   error C2011: 'ConsoleCommandHandler' : 'class' type
>   redefinition  C:\Users\Łukasz\Desktop\IRCClient-master\Magic.cpp  7

and also others

> Error 4   error C2371: 'commandHandler' : redefinition; different basic
>   types C:\Users\Łukasz\Desktop\IRCClient-master\Magic.cpp  62
>
> Error 9   error C2084: function 'ThreadReturn inputThread(void *)'
>   already has a
>   body  C:\Users\Łukasz\Desktop\IRCClient-master\Magic.cpp  100
>
> Error 14  error C2027: use of undefined type
>   'ConsoleCommandHandler'   C:\Users\Łukasz\Desktop\IRCClient-master\Magic.cpp  105

here are the files

Magic.cpp

```
#include "Magic.h"

void signalHandler(int signal);


class ConsoleCommandHandler
{
public:
    bool AddCommand(std::string name, int argCount, void(*handler)(std::string /*params*/, IRCClient* /*client*/))
    {
        CommandEntry entry;
        entry.argCount = argCount;
        entry.handler = handler;
        std::transform(name.begin(), name.end(), name.begin(), towlower);
        _commands.insert(std::pair<std::string, CommandEntry>(name, entry));
        return true;
    }

    void ParseCommand(std::string command, IRCClient* client)
    {
        if (_commands.empty())
        {
            std::cout << "No commands available." << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        if (command[0] == '/')
            command = command.substr(1); // Remove the slash

        std::string name = command.substr(0, command.find(" "));
        std::string args = command.substr(command.find(" ") + 1);
        int argCount = std::count(args.begin(), args.end(), ' ');

        std::transform(name.begin(), name.end(), name.begin(), towlower);

        std::map<std::string, CommandEntry>::const_iterator itr = _commands.find(name);
        if (itr == _commands.end())
        {
            std::cout << "Command not found." << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        if (++argCount < itr->second.argCount)
        {
            std::cout << "Insuficient arguments." << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        (*(itr->second.handler))(args, client);
    }

private:
    struct CommandEntry
    {
        int argCount;
        void(*handler)(std::string /*arguments*/, IRCClient* /*client*/);
    };

    std::map<std::string, CommandEntry> _commands;
};

ConsoleCommandHandler commandHandler;

void msgCommand(std::string arguments, IRCClient* client)
{
    std::string to = arguments.substr(0, arguments.find(" "));
    std::string text = arguments.substr(arguments.find(" ") + 1);

    std::cout << "To " + to + ": " + text << std::endl;
    client->SendIRC("PRIVMSG " + to + " :" + text);
};

void joinCommand(std::string channel, IRCClient* client)
{
    if (channel[0] != '#')
        channel = "#" + channel;

    client->SendIRC("JOIN " + channel);
}

void partCommand(std::string channel, IRCClient* client)
{
    if (channel[0] != '#')
        channel = "#" + channel;

    client->SendIRC("PART " + channel);
}

void ctcpCommand(std::string arguments, IRCClient* client)
{
    std::string to = arguments.substr(0, arguments.find(" "));
    std::string text = arguments.substr(arguments.find(" ") + 1);

    std::transform(text.begin(), text.end(), text.begin(), towupper);

    client->SendIRC("PRIVMSG " + to + " :\001" + text + "\001");
}

ThreadReturn inputThread(void* client)
{
    std::string command;

    commandHandler.AddCommand("msg", 2, &msgCommand);
    commandHandler.AddCommand("join", 1, &joinCommand);
    commandHandler.AddCommand("part", 1, &partCommand);
    commandHandler.AddCommand("ctcp", 2, &ctcpCommand);

    while (true)
    {
        getline(std::cin, command);
        if (command == "")
            continue;

        if (command[0] == '/')
            commandHandler.ParseCommand(command, (IRCClient*)client);
        else
            ((IRCClient*)client)->SendIRC(command);

        if (command == "quit")
            break;
    }

#ifdef _WIN32
    _endthread();
#else
    pthread_exit(NULL);
#endif
}
```

Magic.h

```
#ifndef Magic_h
#define Magic_h
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include "src\Thread.h"
#include "src\IRCClient.h"



volatile bool running;

void signalHandler(int signal)
{
    running = false;
}

class ConsoleCommandHandler
{
public:
    bool AddCommand(std::string name, int argCount, void(*handler)(std::string /*params*/, IRCClient* /*client*/));
    void ParseCommand(std::string command, IRCClient* client);
private:
    struct CommandEntry
    {
        int argCount;
        void(*handler)(std::string /*arguments*/, IRCClient* /*client*/);
    };

    std::map<std::string, CommandEntry> _commands;
};
ConsoleCommandHandler commandHandler;

void msgCommand(std::string arguments, IRCClient* client)
{
    std::string to = arguments.substr(0, arguments.find(" "));
    std::string text = arguments.substr(arguments.find(" ") + 1);

    std::cout << "To " + to + ": " + text << std::endl;
    client->SendIRC("PRIVMSG " + to + " :" + text);
};

void joinCommand(std::string channel, IRCClient* client)
{
    if (channel[0] != '#')
        channel = "#" + channel;

    client->SendIRC("JOIN " + channel);
}

void partCommand(std::string channel, IRCClient* client)
{
    if (channel[0] != '#')
        channel = "#" + channel;

    client->SendIRC("PART " + channel);
}

void ctcpCommand(std::string arguments, IRCClient* client)
{
    std::string to = arguments.substr(0, arguments.find(" "));
    std::string text = arguments.substr(arguments.find(" ") + 1);

    std::transform(text.begin(), text.end(), text.begin(), towupper);

    client->SendIRC("PRIVMSG " + to + " :\001" + text + "\001");
}

ThreadReturn inputThread(void* client)
{
    std::string command;

    commandHandler.AddCommand("msg", 2, &msgCommand);
    commandHandler.AddCommand("join", 1, &joinCommand);
    commandHandler.AddCommand("part", 1, &partCommand);
    commandHandler.AddCommand("ctcp", 2, &ctcpCommand);

    while (true)
    {
        getline(std::cin, command);
        if (command == "")
            continue;

        if (command[0] == '/')
            commandHandler.ParseCommand(command, (IRCClient*)client);
        else
            ((IRCClient*)client)->SendIRC(command);

        if (command == "quit")
            break;
    }

#ifdef _WIN32
    _endthread();
#else
    pthread_exit(NULL);
#endif
}
#endif
```

Comment: This is not C. Please don't add unrelated tags.

Comment: What are you defining the class again in the .cpp file for? You already have the definition in the header, which you've `#include`d. You only need to define its member functions - like this: `bool ConsoleCommandHandler::AddCommand(...) { ... }`

Comment: nice to see actual error messages in the question.  The issue is very basic, so this [link](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/89-class-code-and-header-files/) does a reasonable explanation of classes in header and source files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you define the class in both the .cpp and .h file. Remember, when you #include something, the compiler just replaces the #include directive with the contents of the file. So your "Magic.cpp" file looks something like this:

```
//// from Magic.h
#ifndef Magic_h
#define Magic_h
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include "src\Thread.h"
#include "src\IRCClient.h"

volatile bool running;

void signalHandler(int signal)
{
    running = false;
}

class ConsoleCommandHandler
{
// ...
};
//// end of #include "Magic.h"

void signalHandler(int signal);

class ConsoleCommandHandler
{
// ...
};
```

You have two definitions of the same class in the same source file.

If you are just trying to implement the member functions, you do it like this:

```
// Magic.h
class ConsoleCommandHandler
{
public:
    bool AddCommand(std::string name, int argCount, void(*handler)(std::string /*params*/, IRCClient* /*client*/));
    // ...
};
```

and

```
// Magic.cpp

#include "Magic.h"

bool ConsoleCommandHandler::AddCommand(std::string name, int argCount, void(*handler)(std::string /*params*/, IRCClient* /*client*/))
{
    // implementation
}
```

--- EDIT ---

Your next problems are with "volatile bool running" and "void signalHandler".

```
//// Magic.h

volatile bool running;

void signalHandler(int signal)
{
    running = false;
}
```

These should go into a .cpp file, otherwise you are defining them in every .cpp file that includes the .h file. Again, remember: #include effectively replaces itself with the contents of the file. Think about that for a moment. You and I know that the "signalHandler" definition is in a .h file, but the compiler *doesn't* - all it sees is that you're defining signalHandler in each cpp file.

Comment: Okay, i made it as kfsone adviced. Now when i compile all of this i get like errors:

`Error 2 error LNK2005: "bool volatile running" (?running@@3_NC) already defined in IRC.obj C:\Users\Łukasz\Desktop\IRCClient-master\Magic.obj`

`Error 3 error LNK2005: "void __cdecl signalHandler(int)" (?signalHandler@@YAXH@Z) already defined in IRC.obj C:\Users\Łukasz\Desktop\IRCClient-master\Magic.obj`

I have no idea what to do with those things...

Comment: You have the body of "signalHandler" in a .h file, you should swap that for the forward declaration, and move 'volatile bool running' into a cpp file too.

Comment: so you say that i have to put it in another filer?

Comment: You have the implementation of "signalHandler" in a .h file which is included in more than one .cpp file, that's why it's saying it's already defined. You either need to make it "static" or just a forward declaration and put the body of signal handler in a .cpp file... Making an edit.

Comment: Yea, i fixed it, missed it earlier. But this only solved the second problem, rest still shows. I can put there all of the errors if it helps